# ERROR: gevent 1.4.0 has requirement greenlet>=0.4.14, but you'll have greenlet 0.4.13 which is incompatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, odoo, greenlets

I am using Windows 10, I install Odoo from source code (https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/aa0554d224337e1d966479a351a3ed059d297765 ).
Python version

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

pip version

```
pip 19.3.1 from c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

I catch error

[image]

```
ERROR: gevent 1.4.0 has requirement greenlet>=0.4.14, but you'll have greenlet 0.4.13 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pytz, Babel, chardet, decorator, docutils, lxml, certifi, idna, urllib3, requests, ebaysdk, feedparser, greenlet, pycparser, cffi, gevent, html2text, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, six, libsass, Mako, pbr, mock, num2words, soupsieve, beautifulsoup4, ofxparse, passlib, Pillow, polib, psutil, psycopg2, pyparsing, pydot, PyPDF2, pyserial, python-dateutil, pyusb, qrcode, reportlab, isodate, attrs, appdirs, requests-toolbelt, defusedxml, cached-property, zeep, python-stdnum, vatnumber, vobject, Werkzeug, XlsxWriter, xlwt, xlrd, pywin32, pypiwin32
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python38-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytz'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You can either upgrade greenlet to the latest version by:

```
pip install --upgrade greenlet --ignore-installed greenlet
```

Or you can install any specific version by:

```
pip install greenlet==0.4.14
```